# How to run command on server side via ssh without logging in

Tags: unix, ssh, remote

I am lazy to login to my server via ssh to execute just one command.

Like I need to `touch /var/www/dir/file.doc`. Can I do something like:

```
srun root@mydomain.com touch /var/www/dir/file.doc
```

Comment: Best to put the part after touch or any command in general in single quotes so client shell doesn't expand it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, you can do

```
ssh root@mydomain.com touch /var/www/dir/file.doc
```

Comment: OMG :D I didn't even try obvious solution! Thank you